# Deleting the old site and 301 redirect migration to preserve page rank

Tags: seo, web-hosting, 301-redirect, pagerank, migration

So I am looking to completely redesign a site, keep the domain name, but change the host. Every damn article / tutorial for successful website migration I was looking at is assuming that the old site/domain will still be live - to host the .htaccess file.

In my case, the client has a site with some company (one of those cheap site-builder companies for beginners). I need to completely redesign the layout and content of the site, move it to a new host and keep the domain and SEO juice - surprisingly, the site has a very good ranking.

What is the best way to go about this ?
Thank you.

Comment: The old site will *not* be live. Once you point the domain to the new host the old site is dead. Doesn't matter if the files are still there or not.

Comment: that "duplicate" is absolutely not related to my scenario here... The thing is, once I stop using the services of the old host, they will shut down the hosting completely. In order to do a 301 redirect, all traffic still has to go through the old site. It doesn't have to be live, but the htaccess file has to be stored somewhere.

Comment: But how are users going to get to it if the domain no longer points there? Your .access with the redirects go in your *new* site.

Comment: Ye, now I figured out that the access file is hosted on the new server. Don't know why I assumed it has to be on the old one (which kind of made more sense to me) - I guess because everyone was recommending that the old site stays live.